# how to handle bad request exception in flurl

Tags: c#, visual-studio, controller, flurl

I am totally new to Flurl.I am trying to call api and i deliberately passed invalid apikey in paramter and then api fails saying "Forbidden" and with error code 403. How can i handle that in Exception?

```
 public async Task<myResponse> MyService(myRequest request)
    {
        try
        {


            return await new Flurl.Url("https://myapi.com/rest/age?apikey=XXXXXXXX").PostJsonAsync(apirequest).ReceiveJson<myResponse>();
        }
        catch (FlurlHttpException ex)
        {
            var statusCode = await ex.GetResponseJsonAsync<myResponse>();
            return await ex.GetResponseJsonAsync<myResponse>();

        }
```

I want to throw my own custom exception if i get status code 403 but currently it fails on line `var statusCode = await ex.GetResponseJsonAsync<myResponse>();`
        }

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I want to throw my own custom exception if i get status code 403

There's 2 ways to do this. The first is to simply rethrow from a catch block (`catch`/`when` is handy here):

```
try
{
    ...
}
catch (FlurlHttpException ex) when (ex.Call.HttpStatus == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
{
    throw new MyException(...);
}
```

The second way is to prevent Flurl from throwing by using [`AllowHttpStatus`](https://flurl.io/docs/error-handling/#allowing-non-2xx-responses):

```
var resp = await "https://myapi.com/rest/age?apikey=XXXXXXXX"
    .AllowHttpStatus("4xx")
    .PostJsonAsync(apirequest);

if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
{
    throw new MyException(...);
}
```

One caveat with the second approach is that you're left with a "raw" [`HttpResponseMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage) that you'll need to deserialize yourself, since Flurl's `ReceiveJson` chains off a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`, and you've already awaited that `Task`. But deserializing it yourself [is not that hard](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/blob/master/src/Flurl.Http/HttpResponseMessageExtensions.cs#L29-L32), there's a [planned enhancement](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/354) that will address this in the near future, or you could always use this hacky little work-around:

```
await Task.FromResult(resp).ReceiveJson<myResponse>();
```

Honestly, I'd probably go with the first approach. `FlurlHttpException` has some handy methods like `GetResponseJsonAsync<T>` that allows you to deserialize the error body if it's JSON, or `GetResponseStringAsync` if you just need the raw string.

Comment: Just to add one thing to that excellent answer -- Flurl also supports the `AllowAnyHttpStatus()` option.

Comment: Does .AllowHttpStatus("4xx") imply literal 'xx' or are these supposed to be substituted by actual values like  .AllowHttpStatus("400") or  .AllowHttpStatus("403")?

Comment: @AlekDavis "x" or "*" are treated as wildcards. https://flurl.dev/docs/error-handling/#allowing-non-2xx-responses